# Expression of number of people

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление, склонение, числительные

I have two questions about expressions of number of people in Russian:

1. Once when buying tickets at кассы, I heard the expression "три взрослых". I thought with numbers 2-4, we use the genitive singular form. So why is it not "три взрослого" here?
2. Another time when me and my friends entered a restaurant, I heard the waiter say "четверых", which I guess is the genitive form of "четверо". Can anyone explain to me why we use the genitive case here?

Thank you!

Comment: For 1: it could be an omission: `Три взрослых [билета, пожалуйста].` For 2: It's unclear, the only thing I can come up with is mishearing plus an usual omission `[Столик] **на** четверых, [пожалуйста].`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm still a bit confused, though. For 1, why do you use "взрослых " in "Три взрослых билета"? Isn't билета here in genitive singular, but then взрослых is in genitive plural? For 2, I actually heard this expression more than once. So after "Столик на...", do you use genitive of a collective numeral? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am using this intuitively, so a proper grammatical answer is hard for me, I am sort of reasoning backwards. It's `три`, and not `пять`, so it's not "mass plural", but this "few ones" plural. In this case `два билета`, `три билета` is nominative and accusative (they coincide). (But:  `пять билетов`.) In the second example, my bad, I still omitted too much. It's `Столик на четверых человек`. Ellipsis is hard!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The 'genitive singular' rule only applies to nouns. For adjectives (or nouns that decline like adjectives e.g. запята́я) it's genitive or nominative *plural*: два взро́слых биле́та, два ста́рых дру́га, две мировы́х войны́. On the choice between the genitive and the nominative for adjectives, see [this question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14915/can-anyone-clear-up-some-discrepancies-between-rules-for-numeraladjectivenoun?rq=1).
2. You normally ask for a table *for* a number of people: сто́лик *на* четверы́х, пожа́луйста! The preposition **на** calls for an accusative which matches the genitive for animate nouns/numerals. (In your case the waiter might have preempted your request with "Сто́лик на четверы́х?") If you are asked: Ско́лько вас? (How many of you?), you reply in the nominative: че́тверо.